# Variable keeps going undefined

Tags: javascript, tabs, jquery-selectors, axios

I keep getting an error stating createTabs is not a function when it clearly is. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried renaming my variables then I just get undefined in the other ones that have been set.

```
const createTabs = document.querySelector('.tabs')
console.log('Yooo', createTabs)

axios.get('https://lambda-times-backend.herokuapp.com/topics')
   .then((data) =>{
    // gives results from the server
    console.log('response', data)
    let tabs = data.data
    console.log('Yooo', tabs)
    const element =createTabs(tabs)
    console.log('Rip Nip the Great', tabs)
    tabs.appendChild(element)
   })

   .catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error', error);
   })


Error TypeError: createTabs is not a function
    at index.js:21
```

Comment: `createTabs` holds the html element with class `.tabs` and is not a function. You are using it as a function `createTabs()`.

Comment: Ok. took me a min to see what you meant but you were right! That fixed it. Thank you so much@randomSoul